# -webkit-line-clamp: 2 not working in ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic4

I am using `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` to limit the number of lines appearing in an ionic4 app, but it does not comes up as expected on initial load. Instead, it comes up when I edit the css using inspect in chrome. Is there any workaround to fix it? The css used is:

```
display: -webkit-box;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
p {
  width: 300px !important;
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3 !important
}
```

```html
<p>
  In this example the <code>-webkit-line-clamp</code> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <code>3</code>, which means the text is clamped after three lines.
  An ellipsis will be shown at the point where the text is clamped.
</p>
```

- Make a `class` if u want to use it multiple times or `id` if you want to use it once
- Then implement that `class or id` in your root css files(global or variable) by using `'!important'`
- It will surely work for you

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nandi.development

Comment: No it is still not working. It was working fine for me in ionic 3 but in ionic 4 it is not working

Comment: hi i tried it in both ionic 3 and 4. And its working fine in both. also tried once by using it inline

Comment: No, for me it is not working when i just edit some css in inspect it works but on reloading it never persists

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the exact same issue and also made a question regarding it here: [Ionic 4: -webkit-line-clamp property not applying on inital load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750213/ionic-4-webkit-line-clamp-property-not-applying-on-inital-load)

After days of trying to figure out what has been causing this. I have found that in my case I have `ion-slides` (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) implemented in my HTML (The same HTML file where I am facing this issue) which seems to be causing for all my styles to still apply besides from `-webkit-line-clamp: 2`

When I remove all instances of `ion-slides` within that file then my `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` css rule applies correctly on initial load. I'm still trying to figure out how I can have both `ion-slides` and `-webkit-line-clamp: 2` however i'll update this answer if I end up finding a proper solution.

**UPDATE**

In my particular case. I have `ion-slides` and an *ngFor loop to create mutilple `ion-slide` depending on the data returned. I noticed that I would be rendering the `ion-slides` last as it was dependent on the data returned from a HTTP call which seemed to have an impact on the rest of the HTML elements and their styling (In this case the `-webkit-line-clamp` rule) when the `ion-slides` was fully rendered on the page.

The problem seems to be based on a timing issue and the solution for my particular case was to fetch the data first for the `ion-slides` content and then the rest after that. I know this may be quite a vague answer but this issue seems to be very edge case-y and I hope this helps you to resolving this issue.

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that when I thought I had the issue fixed, I started running into again. There is a module that exists that can provide the same functionality as the CSS rule here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ellipsis) however I noticed when loading many elements, it can have a slight performance impact. If you don't want to face this performance impact. You can limit the width and height of the element to limit the amount of characters shown

Answer (score 1):

Remember to check for `white-space`, especially if you are inside `<ion-label>`:

```css
p {
    width: 300px !important;
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3 !important
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 4 you have to add `style="-webkit-box-orient: vertical"` to the html element
For example:

```
<p style="-webkit-box-orient: vertical">
In this example the <code>-webkit-line-clamp</code> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <code>3</code>, which means the text is clamped after three lines.
  An ellipsis will be shown at the point where the text is clamped.
</p>
```

```
p {
 width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
}
```